# DT Swiss Revolution spokes for touring?

Tags: touring, spokes

I’m building a set of bikes for my wife and I. Both are Surly Bridge Club frames, and we’ll initially be running WTB KOM Tough i40 rims with 2.8in Schwalbe tires.

I purchased some DT Swiss Revolution 2.0mm spokes to build the wheels. But I’m now questioning if these are too light.

I’m about 200lbs and we plan to carry some load on our bikes, mostly in frame packs. Mostly on gravel trails, 2-tracks, and similar.

I’ve never broken a spoke, even when riding the full Great Divide, across South America, or on any daily rides, using a mix of wheels with one being a 28 spoke.

Does anyone recommend against using DT Swiss Revolution 2.0mm spokes for this use? Should I move up to Alpine III or something in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, do not use them here.

They will be impossible to get to full tension without windup on a rim even remotely as stout as that. What's likely to result is a wheelset that could have been rock solid will have constant issues with spokes going loose.

If you want to run fancy spokes, Supercomps are about as light as make sense here, and the 1.8mm tips give the advantage of much more breakage-resistant nipples for a given material choice, which is a nice thing on a disc brake touring bike getting off-road use.

Normal 2.0/1.8 would be the more standard choice. They make it easiest to deal with windup and get a stable build.

Comment: “They will be impossible to get to full tension without windup on a rim even remotely as stout as that.” Isn’t that mostly a matter of wheel building skill? You could even grip the spoke with pliers close to the nipple if you are concerned about windup. It’s been said that spokes with a thin middle section are great for durable wheels because they are more elastic (allowing a more even load distribution).

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll swap out the Revolutions for Champion or Alpine IIIs.

Comment: @Nathan Knutsen - would you recommend the Champion 2.0 or the Alpine IIIs over one another? The Alpine's appear to cost nearly double the Champion's on the sites I'm looking at.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Neither. In DT's selection 2.0/1.8 is called Competition.

Comment: So Competition over those other 2 options?

Comment: In my opinion yes. Alpine III is expensive, doesn't fit all hubs and the extra thickness isn't that useful. Single butted has the most elastic part of spoke at the bend, which should be protected from flexing.

Comment: @Michael no, pliers won't help. You can't grab a round spoke hard enough to keep it from rotating without deforming it. You can do it to non round aero spokes, though. To adjust thin spokes you need to push the rim so that the spoke is loosened.

Comment: @ojs: I’ve done it, you just have to use grease on the threads and you can easily go beyond 1200N spoke tension.

Comment: The problem isn't tension but windup.

Comment: I'm also not a fan of Alpine 3s other than on hubs that really want the extra big gauge. The extra material can create the illusion of being a shield against breakage, but lack of material isn't the problem really. I would go either Competitions or Supercomps, brass nipples either way. I do think Supercomps are probably the "best" for this sort of build.

Comment: About Alpine III: Today every hub is a hub that really wants the extra big gauge. In the past, hubs had holes through which the spokes barely fit. However, in order to speed up wheel lacing, today hubs have far too big spoke holes. A standard 2.0mm/1.8mm/2.0mm spoke is a far worse fit than a 2.34mm/1.8mm/2.0mm Alpine III. The Alpine III is slower to lace but a better fit a the hub. I agree this is idiotic, but since you can't today buy hubs with reasonably sized spoke holes, this is the only way to get a good fit at the hub.